# Comparar fechas con powershell

Tags: powershell

Buenas tardes;

Tengo un inconveniente al realizar una comparación de fechas con powershell, las fechas con las que hago la comparación se encuentran en un archivo CSV, ejemplo:

```
titulo    - recordatorio - vence
Noticia01 - 13/01/2018   - 30/01/2018
Noticia02 - 14/01/2018   - 30/01/2018
```

donde, la fecha recordatorio hara una comparación con la fecha actual y si es son iguales me enviara una alerta.

Este es el script en powershell

```
    $csv = "datos.csv"
    $datos = Import-CSV $csv
    $fr = ForEach ($var in $datos)
        {
            $var.recordatorio
        }

    $fa = Get-Date -Format d

    if($fa -eq $fr)
        {
            echo "está proximo a vencer la siguiente noticia"           
        }

    else
        {
            echo "no hacer nada"
        }
```

pero al momento de ejecutar y comparar fechas no lo hace, por favor su apoyo en que me estoy equivocando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero lo que deberías de hacer para facilitar las cosas es normalizar el archivo *.csv*, para utilizar por ejemplo un delimitador más común como lo es la coma (,).

El archivo quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
titulo,recordatorio,vence
Noticia01,13/01/2018,30/01/2018
Noticia02,14/01/2018,30/01/2018
```

Esto permite que al importar el *.csv* no necesites adicionar nada. Tomando las 2 primeras líneas del código obtenemos lo siguiente.

```
PS C:\Users\vmsilvamolina> $datos

titulo    recordatorio vence     
------    ------------ -----     
Noticia01 13/01/2018   30/01/2018
Noticia02 14/01/2018   30/01/2018
```

Luego de esto, tenemos que $datos es un System.Array, lo que nos permite recorrerlo usando [foreach](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-5.1) de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach ($item in $datos) {
    if ($item.recordatorio -eq $fa) {
        Write-host "Está proximo a vencer la siguiente noticia:" $item.titulo
    } else {
        Write-host "No pasa nada"
    }
}
```

Ahí modifiqué para que imprima el mensaje definido de vencimiento adicionando el título de la noticia.

> Con los datos del archivo .csv del ejemplo no cumple con la condición para desplegar el mensaje de vencimiento.

Te adjunto todo el código:

```
$csv = 'C:\Users\vmsilvamolina\Desktop\prueba.csv'
$datos = Import-CSV $csv

#Formato de fecha
$fa = Get-Date -Format dd/MM/yyyy

foreach ($item in $datos) {
    if ($item.recordatorio -eq $fa) {
        Write-host "Se está por vencer!" $item.titulo
    } else {
        Write-host "No pasa nada"
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

De la solicitud expresada en los comentarios modifiqué el código para que imprima todas las noticias que cumplen la condición, separadas por una coma:

$csv = 'C:\Users\vmsilvamolina\Desktop\prueba.csv'
$datos = Import-CSV $csv

$fa = Get-Date -Format dd/MM/yyyy
$noticias = $null

foreach ($item in $datos) {
    if ($item.recordatorio ) {
        $noticias += $item.titulo + ", "
    } else {
        Write-host "No pasa nada"
    }
}

Write-host "Se está por vencer!" $noticias.Substring(0,$noticias.Length-2)

> Se utilizó el método [Substring()](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692804.aspx) para borrar la última coma (,) que se agregaba al final de la cadena.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he probado y me funciono. Tengo una duda y espero me puedas ayudar, al ejecutar el script me indica  --- Se está por vencer! x cosa, pero si tengo varias cosas por vencer me indicaria --- Se está por vencer!" x1 - Se está por vencer!" x2 - Se está por vencer!" x3. y si lo quisiera simplicar a solo una opción por ejemplo: Se está por vencer! - x1 - x2 - x3, se podrá realizar dicha acción ?

Comment: Lo que habría que hacer en vez de utilizar el Write-Host, sería guardar los títulos de cada noticia que cumple con la condición y luego al finalizar el recorrido por el array imprimir el string "Se está por vencer" con el string que contiene todos los títuloss. Si no queda muy claro, agrego otra respuesta con el código en cuestión.

Comment: Por fa, me ayudarías mucho si me ayudas con ese código.